# Meta on StackExchange

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange, meta

I would love to see meta.stackoverflow.com on stackexchange.com, in all three categories.

I do know that meta somehow is in an awkward position, as it from its naming scheme probably should be called meta.stackexchange.com with its content split into meta.stackoverflow.com for meta stuff solely for SO, and meta.stackexchange.com for meta on all SE sites.

But for the moment, meta is a site that differs quite from other meta sites like meta.gaming.stackexchange.com and therefore has its right of standing on the list.

Answer (score 2):

This is effectively completed since `meta.stackexchange.com` redirects here now.

Comment: Does that mean meta.stackoverflow.com is effectively the meta of all stackexchange?

Comment: @Jim, [yes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about).