# General meta stackexchange site

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta

Where's the right place to ask meta questions about stack exchange in general, not just about a specific stack exchange site?

For example, I tried to find out how to put links into comments and found the answer on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/links-in-comments). (I'm sure I could have found the answer also on meta stackoverflow, but that's beside the point.)

Where would I ask such a question? Is there a general meta stackexchange site? Take this question for example, it is not connected to stackoverflow, I could have asked it also on meta.beer.stackexchange.com.

Interestingly, meta.stackexchange.com redirects to meta.stackoverflow.com. Can I consider this meta site as the most general one?

Comment: *sometimes* the per-site metas have answered questions more clearly (and more searchable) than the network wide meta.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meta on StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60819/meta-on-stackexchange)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: @gnat That's kind of an awful target as it doesn't explain at all what meta means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the meta for the whole network in addition to being Stack Overflow's meta, however, [that is about to change,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange?rq=1) and meta.stackexchange should be a thing soon enough. So for the time being, this is indeed the place to ask general questions concerning the whole network.

Comment: Dont be crazy. Just 6 to 8.